# Loading My UserControl dynamically and asynchronously on each button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

In my page I have a 'Button' when I click it, it loads an instance of my 'UserControl' to a 'PlaceHolder' .. I've used the 'UpdatePanel' but it was a hazard! .. I think it's because the Asp.Net 'Ajax' sends the whole page to the server and behind the scenes it actually causes a full PostBack. and it will help me if I could implement a partial PostBack so I won't need to save or access my database each time I reload or click the button to re-assign the values to my UserControl.

So I was hopping for some samples implementing a partial PostBack to load only one instance of my UserControl.

I can't post the code in my page here because it's a REAL MESS! .. but if you really need this to help me then maybe I could send this and post a clean solution here on the question.

Thanks for your time .. I hope there's some simple answers to my question because I'm really hopeless here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UpdatePanel always causes a postback to the server for the entire page, and only updates the UI's within the update panel.  That's just how it will always work.  If you only want to load a user control, consider using a JQuery approach to pull the user control from the server and render it via client-side JavaScript.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117475/Load-ASP-Net-User-Control-Dynamically-Using-jQuery
http://samuelmueller.com/2008/12/dynamicloader-plugin-dynamically-loading-asp-net-user-controls-with-jquery/

HTH.